# problema al instalar Microsoft SQL Server 2014 CLR Types 32bits

Tags: sql-server, reportviewer, sql-server-2014

antes de instalar reportviewer me pide instalar **Microsoft SQL Server 2014 CLR Types**  de 32bits,
*tengo el de 64bits que funciona a la perfeccion en una maquina de 64bits*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Aqui](https://mega.nz/#F!PsZX1YKa!oBGCI1Dlf0A_gpio3dru-Q) te dejo todo lo que necesitas para hacer funcionar Solo [RerportViewer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251671.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)